# Rescaling table, based on webpage's size

Tags: html, css, html-table

In the photo below, there's a div, in which I have a table with some content in it, and as I re-scale the web browser's page, the table goes out of the div.

[image]

What I'd like to do is to make the table smaller when it's re-scaled and still show everything that's inside of it, without the use of a scrollbar or anything like that.

**EDIT**

```css
#profileTable{
 width:auto;
 text-align:left;
 color:#000080;
 padding:30px 60px;
 border:1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius:4px;
 background-color:white;
 margin: 0 50px 50px;
}


#content{
 margin: 0px 60px 0px;
 background-color:#E9E9E9;
 border:solid 1px grey;
 flex: 1;
 clear:both;
 position:relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="content" >
        <h2><center>Your profile</center></h2>     
        <table id="profileTable">
          <tr>       
            <th>Username:</th>    
            <td>CONTENT</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>       
            <th>First name:</th>    
            <td>CONTENT</td>
          </tr>        
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add your html,css in this question.

Comment: `table{width:XX%;table-layout:fixed;}` https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/table-layout  if content doesn't need a table, then use regular tags

Comment: is there an html table there or not ? which tag is the CSS related to ? center is an obsolete tag since ages ago, do not use it :(

Comment: the table is in PHP, but by using HTML table tags

Comment: @GCyrillus haha ok I'll replace the center tag , but the css for the table doesn't work for me. Is that because of the center tag?

Comment: no it doesn't mess with the css. difficult to really understand what's going on without a piece of code that reproduce your issue ( add some relevant css and an html table with fake text or fake image) :) use your snippet to update your html and place the css

Comment: @GCyrillus updated my post including the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you used `flex`, you might use it too for `tr` to allow wrapping without mediaqueries (note this `table` could also be a list `ul` or `dl`)

horizontal margins can be turned to width with calc() and min-width, so they can visually collapse

example

```css
#profileTable {
  text-align: left;
  color: #000080;
  padding: 30px 60px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  min-width: 270px;/* remove or tune this to your needs */
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
  /* word-break:break-all; not really a good idea */
}

#content {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  min-width: 360px;/* remove or tune this to your needs */
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #E9E9E9;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  flex: 1;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
}


/* are you already using flex ? */

tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  min-width: 5em;/* remove or tune this to your needs */
}

td {
  flex: 1;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h2>Your profile</h2>
  <table id="profileTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Username:</th>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>First name:</th>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh God, you're a savior!! Thanks very much !!

Answer (score 0):

Look at `table-responsive` feature in Bootstrap.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

add

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-responsive">
```

And then